Error while upgrading codebase from Sitecore 9.3 to 10.2
I am working on a Sitecore upgrade project from version 9.3 to 10.2, and we are encountering an issue while upgrading the Sitecore DLLs through NuGet. Below is the error we are receiving:
Error:
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for "Website.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions'.
Detected package downgrade: Sitecore.Kernel from 10.2.0 to 9.3.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

Any help would be appreciated.

What is this Website.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions?

I encountered a similar issue in a previous project, though it was with a different version upgrade. Here are a couple of suggestions you can try:

Update .NET Version: I assume you've already upgraded your .NET framework to at least version 4.8.
Update NuGet Packages: If you're using Visual Studio 2019, try manually updating the package version in your .csproj or
packages.config file, depending on where it's referenced in your
project. After making the change, close and reopen Visual Studio.
Upon reloading the solution, it should automatically install the
updated NuGet packages. I suggest trying this with one project first.
Consider Upgrading to Visual Studio 2022: If possible, try using Visual Studio 2022. The issue you're facing might not occur in this
version.
Reinstall the Kernel Package: You could try removing the Sitecore.Kernel package reference and then adding it again. This
might resolve any lingering issues with package dependencies.

Please give these steps a try and let me know if they resolve the issue.

Thanks Vishal! It works

You will need to upgrade the dependency of Sitecore.Kernel dll in every project in order to resolve this issue.
This issue might be happening because in some of the project package upgrade for Sitecore.Kernel is detected i.e. 10.2.0, whereas in some of the project it is still referring older version i.e. 9.3.0.
You can find the references of Sitecore.Kernel 9.3.0 in your solution and upgrade it to 10.2.0 on each project. Once the package upgrade is done for all the project, you can clear the nuget cache by going to the following path inside Visual Studio.
Tools-> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Clear All Nuget Cache

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thanks, Chirag, for the response. However, while updating the version of Sitecore.Kernel, I am encountering this error.

@shilpasaini can you remove the sitecore.kernel package from that solution you are trying to upgrade...and then install the sitecore 10.2 kernel version. Hope this helps

Also make sure you are checking sitecore.kernel references in the referenced project as well..
